# How to get configured XSRF header name in angular?

Tags: angular, csrf

When you configure XSRF protection in Angular, you can specify custom cookie and header names:

```
imports: [
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
    cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
    headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
  }),
],
```

Is there a way to get those values later on to use for example in your own service/interceptor/component?

I can see that there are injection tokens defined for XSRF_COOKIE_NAME and XSRF_HEADER_NAME in Angular sources at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts#L27C14-L27C31, but they dont seem to be exposed, because injecting them does not work:

```
import { XSRF_HEADER_NAME } from '@angular/common/http'; // ERROR: Module "@angular/common/http" has no exported member 'XSRF_HEADER_NAME'.ts(2305)
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public constructor(
    @Inject(XSRF_HEADER_NAME) private readonly _xsrfHeaderName: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Or am I importing it from wrong place?

I know that I can work around this by creating my own injection token with the desired value and use that in my service, but that's not the point of this question. I'm specifically interested if there is a way to get the configured values passed to `HttpClientXsrfModule`.

Answer (score 0):

No, without succumbing to workarounds you mentioned, or digging deep into Angular internals, like `HttpClientXsrfModule.ɵinj` or some such.

Perhaps [Token extractor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) could help you with whatever you're looking for? What is your goal here?

Comment: Thats unfortunate, but thanks anyway. The goal is to add the configured XSRF header to a custom service that does not use HttpClient. I already use there the `HttpXsrfTokenExtractor` to get the token value, but I wanted to also get the header name from already present XSRF configuration (ideally without introducing any workaronuds, but that seems impossible)

Comment: Yep, the simplest thing to do is the injection token, as you already suggested.

Comment: I opened a feature request at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51193 so maybe one day it will be possible without workarounds

Comment: Good, I like the thoroughness. FWIW I still think it's better to leave something that seems very niche to be in a different library, rather then the default Angular's http module. But I may have a limited perspective here so it's definitely a valid request and idea.